# Understanding probability of getting a $6$ in $4$ throws of a single die

Tags: probability

Obviously, the sample space is $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$. Let $A_i$ be event that $6$ does not appear on $i$th roll of the die. So $P(A_4) = 5/6$ and hence

$$ P( our \; event ) = 1 - 5/6 = 1/6 $$

But, in my notes, the answer is

$$ 1 - (5/6)^4 $$

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's the probability none of the four throws are a 6, not just the last throw

Comment: the throws are independend, so you will get $$\frac{5}{6}$$ in the first, $\frac{5}{6}\frac{5}{6}$ in the second and so on $$\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^4$$

Comment: Die is singular; dice is plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PS: The sample space is $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^4$, representing the *four* independent throws of the die.

You are given the probability that a `6` does not show on the $i$-th throw of the die. Clearly this will be for any $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.$$\forall i\in\{1,2,3,4\}:\mathsf P(A_i)=5/6$$

Notice that events $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ will be independent, since they do each apply to different independent rolls of the die.   So the probability of their intersection is simple the product of their marginal probabilities. $$\mathsf P(\bigcap_{i=1}^4 A_i)=(5/6)^4$$

But this is for the event that a six shows on none of the four throws.  We seek the probability for the complement: that a six shows on some of the four throws.

$$\mathsf P(\bigcup_{i=1}^4 A_i^{^\complement})=1-(5/6)^4$$

Answer (score 1):

If you throw the die four times, obviously the sample space is *not* $\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$.
After all, the sequence "$1$, then $2$, then another $1$, then $4$" is not represented by any of the single numbers $1,$ $2,$ $3,$ $4,$ $5,$ or $6,$ which are all the members of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

A sample space for four throws could be written
$$\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}.$$
There are $6^4$ elements in this set.
One of these elements is the ordered tuple $(1,2,1,4),$ which is a good representation of the sequence "$1$, then $2$, then another $1$, then $4$."

The event "get a $6$" in this context means that the sequence of rolls matches at least one of the patterns $(6,x,y,z),$ $(x,6,y,z),$
$(x,y,6,z),$ or $(x,y,z,6).$
The sequence might even match more than one of the patterns;
for example, $(6,2,4,6)$ is a sequence of rolls in which you get a $6.$

Now think about where the $(5/6)^4$ might come from.